# Why do proofs use "extreme" cases?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

I noticed that quite often proofs go to extremities to show later that there is a contradiction. By extremities I mean that they introduce an object with properties that are either minimal or maximal. For example, when proving "given no vertices have odd degrees, the graph is eulerian", the proof starts with

> Suppose $G$ is **non-eulerian** graph with at least one edge and no vertices of odd degree. Choose such a graph G with **as few edges as possible**. Let $C$ be a closed trail **of maximum possible length** in G.

Later we prove that there is a longer closed trail so there is a contradiction.

The point is I can't completely see when it is necessary to introduce those extremities. Because how I would start is just by assuming the implication is false, so there is a non-eulerian graph G with no vertices having odd degree, and get stuck there hence not reaching any contradiction. So, could you please explain what is the gut feeling or trigger that should hint about introducing those extremities? How to know if I need maximal or minimal property of some object? Should I introduce extremities for every object (e.g. why **as few edges as possible**, can't see how it affects the proof)? Do we even need them? Please elaborate on this, I just want to get some context about this technique.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on how exactly the proof goes? I can't directly see where they used $G$ having as few edges as possible (I would fix a certain non-eulerian graph with no vertices of odd degree and look at the maximum closed trail...)

Comment: @Ekin, unfortunately, I myself can't completely understand how the proof works and it is quite long to write it here. Basically, it says then that $C$ is not Eulerian tour of $G$ by the assumption. Then considers $C$ and $G-E(C)$ as separate graphs and $G-E(C)$ has some component $G'$ with number of edges > 0. Then by the choice of $G$, $G'$ has an Eulerian tour $C'$. Then as $G$ is connected, there is a vertex $v$ in $V(C) \cup V(C')$. Then $CC'$ is a closed trail of $G$ with number of edges longer than in $C$. Hence, contradiction, as $C$ was the longest closed trail in $G$.

Comment: @Ekin, if you are wondering if the proof uses explicitly that property, then no. It doesn't mention any conclusion based on the fact that we have as few as possible edges. Maybe it is implicitly in it but not explicitly stated.